# Java print out a messageBox from main and from another radio button

Tags: java

So, I'm currently in the process of making a bank account gui in Java and I'm having trouble printing out a person's name in a new message box gui after I press a radio button that asks the user for various things.

So I have this in my main:

```
String acctName;
    acctName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the account name:");
```

and it prints out in a dialog box through JOptionPane and my issue is making only the name print out in another messagebox outside the main.

SO, I tried to make a new function:

```
public static void getAcctName()
{
    String acctName;
    acctName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the account name:");
}
```

and call it from the main but I don't know how to make it read a string like this :( . please help

My goal is to make a user input a name and after they press a radio button that asks for various things, a message box will appear that will say the person's name first.

Answer (score 0):

There is a version of showInputDialog() that lets you customize the prompt:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test extends JFrame{

    public Test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400, 300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    }

    private void closeIt(){
        this.getContentPane().setVisible(false);
        this.dispose();
    }

    public void getAcctName(String n) {
        String acctName;
        acctName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                this,
                n + ", enter the account name: ",
                "Get Account Name",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        //...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Test frame = new Test();

        //get the user's name
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "What's your name?");

        //pass the user's name when getting account name
        frame.getAcctName(name);

        frame.closeIt();
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Edwin ! Thanks for the reply ! I was wondering if you knew how to make the name appear, in a messageBox without the Ok and Cancel buttons ?